# Ошибка before statement

Tags: jquery, javascript

Применяю accordion

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script> // jquery

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
        .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

Ругается на первую строчку кода. Пишет `missing ; before statement`
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка находится выше этого куска кода. Проверьте то что идет до него. Или скиньте расширенный исходник.

Вы не подключили библиотеку jQuery. Без нее работать ничего не будет.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Если этот проект у Вас есть на сервере, не могли бы дать ссылку? Для того что бы было возможно лучше вникнуть в проблему. 

Так довольно сложно.

Как я сказал - ошибка скорее всего в коде идущем перед приведенным js. что бы это проверить - напишите вместо вашего кода следующее <script>alert(1);</script> если ошибка все еще будет, значит однозначно она в коде выше.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, ошибка тут:

```
$(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
```

**";"** забыли после строки

И перед

```
.siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
```

скорее всего тоже должно быть "**$(this)**"

Comment: Тогда бы не ругалось на первую строку.

Comment: @Даниил Вендолин, ну даже если ошибка не в этом, то в любом случае - это ошибка

Comment: $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow").siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow"); - это все одно правило.

Comment: Ну тогда надо одной строкой и написать

Comment: Нет, это не является принципиальным, для восприятия - да, лучше. Но на работу не влияет.